# Powershell - CSV - AD Attribute Update

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I'm trying to get AD attributes updated with information from my payroll system. I have a good dump of employee information, and can get most things updated, but I'm having some small problems that hopefully someone much better with Powershell than I can assist with.

--- UpdateInfo.ps1 ---

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users=Import-Csv C:\info_update.csv
foreach($u in $Users)
{
Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($u.employeeID)'" -properties * | set-aduser -replace @{title="$($u.title)";extensionAttribute1="$($u.title)";givenName="$($u.givenName)";initials="$($u.initials)";middleName="$($u.middleName)";sn="$($u.sn)";physicalDeliveryOfficeName="$($u.physicalDeliveryOfficeName)";streetAddress="$($u.streetAddress)";l="$($u.l)";st="$($u.st)";co="$($u.co)";countryCode="$($u.countryCode)";c="$($u.c)";postalCode="$($u.postalCode)";department="$($u.department)"}
}
```

--- info_update.csv ---

```
employeeID,givenName,initials,middleName,sn,name,title,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,streetAddress,l,st,co,countryCode,c,postalCode,department,manager
"111","Smith","Q","Quincy","John","Smith, John Q.","Tech II","Springfield, IL","800 E Monroe St.","Springfield","IL","United States","840","US","62701","IT","540"
```

Two questions:

- I can't get the 'name' field to update. I thought that it was because of the space, but the physicaldeliveryofficename has a space, too...and it's working fine.
- I need to do a lookup for the manager ID (last column), return the DN of the manager, and use that to update the manager attribute.

If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it. I feel like I'm really close, but I'm overlooking something.

Thanks!

---UPDATE---
Thanks to @TheMadTechnician

Here's the final answer.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users=Import-Csv C:\Job_titles.csv
foreach($u in $Users)
{
$Mgr = Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($u.manager)'" | Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($u.employeeID)'" -properties * | set-aduser -replace @{title="$($u.title)";extensionAttribute1="$($u.title)";givenName="$($u.givenName)";displayName="$($u.name)";initials="$($u.initials)";middleName="$($u.middleName)";sn="$($u.sn)";physicalDeliveryOfficeName="$($u.physicalDeliveryOfficeName)";streetAddress="$($u.streetAddress)";l="$($u.l)";st="$($u.st)";co="$($u.co)";countryCode="$($u.countryCode)";c="$($u.c)";postalCode="$($u.postalCode)";department="$($u.department)";manager="$Mgr"} -PassThru | Rename-ADObject -NewName "$($u.name)"
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting trying to set the manager? Piping your AD User object to Set-ADUser -Manager "Bob Smith" should be ok according to the documentation.

Comment: That record has Manager listed as "540". Unless that person's parents had a very sick sense of humor I doubt that is his name. Is there a list someplace that associates that number with a name?

Comment: The manager field lists the manager's employeeID number. For that portion, I need to do a lookup of the DN for that manager employeeID and inject the DN in to the update for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we will use get-aduser and filter on EmployeeID for the manager, and use Select -ExpandProperty for the DistinguishedName property. I also use the -PassThru switch on your Set-ADUser, and pipe it to Rename-ADObject. See how that suits you:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users=Import-Csv C:\info_update.csv
$Managers = Import-Csv C:\Managers.csv
foreach($u in $Users)
{
$Mgr = Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($u.manager)'" | Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($u.employeeID)'" -properties * | set-aduser -replace @{title="$($u.title)";extensionAttribute1="$($u.title)";givenName="$($u.givenName)";initials="$($u.initials)";middleName="$($u.middleName)";sn="$($u.sn)";physicalDeliveryOfficeName="$($u.physicalDeliveryOfficeName)";streetAddress="$($u.streetAddress)";l="$($u.l)";st="$($u.st)";co="$($u.co)";countryCode="$($u.countryCode)";c="$($u.c)";postalCode="$($u.postalCode)";department="$($u.department)";manager="$Mgr"} -PassThru | Rename-ADObject -NewName "$($u.name)"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a list of just the managers. The manager field lists the manager's employeeID number. For that portion, I need to do a lookup of the DN for that manager employeeID and inject the DN in to the update for the user.

Comment: Ok, updated my answer to use Get-ADUser and filter on the employeeID field to get the manager's DN.

Comment: Since I'm pulling everything from the same CSV, should it be something like this? `Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users=Import-Csv C:\info_update.csv
foreach($u in $Users)
{
$Mgr = Get-ADUser -Filter "manager -eq '$($u.manager)'" | Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($u.employeeID)'" -properties * | set-aduser -replace ...";manager="$Mgr"} -PassThru | Rename-ADObject -NewName "$($u.name)"
}`

Comment: Right, sorry, forgot to remove the `$managers =` line. Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I updated my original post with the final code. Thanks @TheMadTechnician

Answer (score 0):

Set-ADUser cannot be used to set Name. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx

Try using Rename-ADObject:

```
    Rename-ADObject [-Identity] <ADObject> [-NewName] <string>
```

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617225.aspx

Comment: Something like this?
`Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($u.employeeID)'" -properties * | set-aduser -replace @{title="$($u.title)";extensionAttribute1="$($u.title)";givenName="$($u.givenName)";initials="$($u.initials)";middleName="$($u.middleName)";sn="$($u.sn)";physicalDeliveryOfficeName="$($u.physicalDeliveryOfficeName)";streetAddress="$($u.streetAddress)";l="$($u.l)";st="$($u.st)";co="$($u.co)";countryCode="$($u.countryCode)";c="$($u.c)";postalCode="$($u.postalCode)";department="$($u.department)"} | Rename-ADObject -NewName "$($u.name)"
}`